# The type or namespace name '"Namespace"' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops

I am trying to build my project by referencing private project using VS2012, it builds successfully on local machine, but I am trying to use Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online, Team Foundation Service) and the build agent set up by Microsoft does not find the namespace.

Tried to re-reference by reading other posts as well checking that target framework is set on all projects to .Net Framework 4, but nothing seems to work, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So I solved the issue, the Visual Studio Team Services error log said that the project was not building because the build configuration was wrong and not assigned to building process, it was set to x86 I change it to Any CPU and now it was build successfully, hope this helps to someone.

Answer (score 0):

if your solution have .cs files i.e. class libraries then build that library separately by right click on it and choose option build, then add reference to the website then it will be cleared.

Comment: I tried that but did not gave any changes Visual Studio Online still gives me back the missing namespace errors

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8bf256fc-836a-4ca7-a953-7d91acb77bfe/error-namespace-missing-microsoftvisualstudioteamfoundation-in-vs2012?forum=tfsgeneral please go through this document ti may help you,

Comment: Did not help, It is very confusing why the Hosted Build Machine does not find the namespace, it is not the only project I am referencing and only this one is causing problem